# Why is PM2 restarting my process?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a very simple HTTP endpoint that can be posted to and drops the payload into a message queue.  Since it should always be running there is no process.exit() so I'm sure it's not exiting on purpose.

I figured it was restarting because of an exception but I've examined the PM2 logs and noted PM2 restarts without any exception being logged.  The only reason I think it's restarting is because the restart number from a "pm2 list" slowly increments throughout the day.

OS: Windows 2012
PM2 Version (memory): 0.15.10
PM2 Version (local): 1.1.3

Any direction on where to start looking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to figure out why a PM2 process restarted if the error log is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049404/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-why-a-pm2-process-restarted-if-the-error-log-is-emp)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049404/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-why-a-pm2-process-restarted-if-the-error-log-is-emp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough there was a process.exit(0) buried in one of the files being required.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your pm2 version for sure, just run `npm install pm2 -g && pm2 update` and it will update your in-memory version of pm2 (thats the daemon running) and restart all your process using the new version.

Comment: How does this even answer the question? This is as helpful as "Restart your computer"